# C++ standard and bind function

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

In the C++ standard (N3797) 20.9.9.1.3 has the following statements about `bind`.

> Returns: A forwarding call wrapper `g` with a nested type `result_type` defined as a synonym for `R`. The effect of `g(u1, u2, ..., uM)` shall be `INVOKE(fd, std::forward<V1>(v1), std::forward<V2>(v2), ..., std::forward<VN>(vN), R)`, where the values and types of the bound arguments `v1, v2, ..., vN` are determined as specified below. The copy constructor and move constructor of the forwarding call wrapper shall throw an exception if and only if the corresponding constructor of `FD` or of any of the types `TiD` throws an exception.

But there's no mention of the unbound arguments `u1 u2 ... uM` in the call wrapper. Am I missing something? Shouldn't the statement in the middle read as follows?

> ... The effect of `g(u1, u2, ..., uM)` shall be `INVOKE(fd, std::forward<V1>(v1), std::forward<V2>(v2), ..., std::forward<VN>(vN), std::forward<U1>(u1), ... std::forward<UM>(um), R)`, where ...

Comment: What does STL have to do with the question?

Comment: Because the function being described `bind` is in STL. But if you feel it's inappropriate, I'll remove it.

Comment: `std::bind` came into C++ [from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html), not [from STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... are determined as specified below:

> The values of the bound arguments v1, v2, ..., vN and their
>   corresponding types V1, V2, ..., VN depend on the types TiD derived
>   from the call to bind and the cv -qualifiers cv of the call wrapper g
>   as follows:
>
> - if TiD is reference_wrapper, the argument is tid.get() and its type Vi is T&;
> - if the value of is_bind_expression::value is true, the argument is
>       tid(std::forward(uj)...) and its type Vi is result_of::type;
> - if the value j of is_placeholder::value is not zero, the argument is std::forward(uj) and its type Vi is Uj&&;
> - otherwise, the value is tid and its type Vi is TiD cv &.

In other words:

- If you bound a reference wrapper, it unwraps that and passes it into the wrapped function object
- If you bound another result of `std::bind`, or anything else which `std::is_bind_expression` evaluates as true, it passes all of the arguments from the call site to that and passes the result to the wrapped function object
- If you bound a placeholder object, then it passes in the appropriate call site argument
- Otherwise, it passes the bound argument

Comment: Thanks for answering it. I made the connection shortly after posting the question and just got around to it.